# ASP.NET Core configurations issue with rc1 vs rc2 and more

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using the `DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe` with Visual Studio Update 3.

I am unable to migrate code to read settings in the appsettings.json file from an MVC6 app.

The code uses the `@inject` `Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel.IOptions` Settings syntax in a razor file to read the configuration.

The only version of `Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel.IOptions` available is rc1, whereas the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` version is rc2.

Therefore I am getting the 'ambiguous call' error referred to in a related .net github issue:

```asp
Error CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure. This error is about using ANY rc1 version concurrently with any rc2 version of any library/component listed in project.json.
```

leaving out the `Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel.Options` part I get this further error:

```asp
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

Of course, I realize this is part of the worst (or most visible) release mess in ms-land history. And such is the cost of progress. But I still would like to know the answer, please.

Comment: The github issues I'm referring to here are these: 
https://github.com/aspnet/Options/issues/97?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container
and   https://github.com/aspnet/Options/issues/91

Comment: you should be using RTM not rc2 or rc1 at this point. To solve this kind of problem would need to see your project.json file and also your global.json. most likely you are referencing some wrong versions for packages